# Optimize long if statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a if statement inside a loop that sets a variable to a specific country name if it matches the condition, that is, if the parameter contains the country name.

The parameters are a list of paths that contain a country name in different positions, i.e. `C:\\some\\path\\text_country_text.xlsx` or `C:\\some\\path\\text_text_country_text.xlsx`

The if statement is pretty long at the moment because it checks a rather long list of countries. The code I wrote works but it does not look really optimized. Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
def my_function(*args): 
    for country in args:
        if "Australia" in country:
            country_name = "Australia"
        elif "Austria" in country:
            country_name = "Austria"
        # etc. for many countries
```

Comment: If the country name is in the same position within the paths then just extract it, perhaps comparing it to a list (or dictionary) of the names.

Comment: Of course this is hugely inefficient, but it would help if you specify more clearly what exactly is the required input and output of the function.

Comment: @CongMa The input is a list of paths to Excel country tables. The function is supposed to be an automation for inserting values from these tables to a global/general Excel table. This works. I have to put the names of the countries in a column next to the repsective values. I get all values from the tables but the country name is only in the paths and not in the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:
Countries = [ all countries]
Code:

```
for country in args:
  for i in Countries:
        if i in country:
          country_name = i
```

Comment: Many thanks! I haven't thought about this simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't know exactly where the country name is within your country string (so you can't use slicing or a regex to extract the relevant portion), you could adapt your approach to take a `list` of countries, and then use a generator expression with `next()` to extract the country name:

```
next((c_name for c_name in countries if c_name in country), 'Unknown')
```

Examples:

```
>>> countries = ['Australia', 'Austria']
>>> country = '#Austrian_man#'
>>> next((c_name for c_name in countries if c_name in country), 'Unknown')
'Austria'
>>> country = '#AustrTYPO_man#'
>>> next((c_name for c_name in countries if c_name in country), 'Unknown')
'Unknown'
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't known about next() so far. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it, and to show the power of `set`s, it is possible to solve this with only one `for` loop and a `set.intersection()` call:

```
def my_function(*args):
    countries = set(['Austria', 'Australia', 'Brazil', 'Denmark'])
    for country_name in countries.intersection(args):
        print(country_name)
```

Thus, the loop will only loop over countries that are both among the input arguments and in the predefined `countries` set.

Comment: Thanks! I might adjust my code according to this. My input are 140 Excel tables. It is probably a good idea to be more efficient.